# How to create a single HTML report file using protractor-html-reporter for Multi-capabilities?

Tags: npm, protractor, automated-tests, jasmine-reporters

We are using [Protractor-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter) to create HTML reporting. Report is generated for each browser if we are using multi-capabilities.
I want to know is there any way to create a single HTML report if we are using multi-capabilities?

HTML report is generated using xml file(Using jasmineRreporters).Please find the codes below in config file.

```
  //This is to generate xml file
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({

        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: xmlOutputPath,
        modifiedSuiteName: true,
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'

    }));


 //to generate html reporting
onComplete: function () {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');

        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'Test Report',
            outputPath: HtmlreportPath,
            screenshotPath: ScreenshotPath,
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true

        };
        new HTMLReport().from(xmlOutputPath + '/xmloutput.xml', testConfig);
    });
},
```

Comment: Try thisif this works - You will need to merge the separate xml reports from jasmine reporter. And pass that merged file to the HTMLReport(). The code for doing this has to be moved to afterLaunch() which is called only once atthe end, irrespective of number of capabilities. There are no global variables as webdriver is shut down so you will need to change code accordingly. For merging xml you can look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/smf-xmlmerge-js

Comment: Do we have any working sample code for this?